# FIM Synchronization service wont start

Tags: user-profile, fim

I am trying to sync SharePoint with AD.

When starting FIMsynchronizationService the below error message appears:

> "windows could not start the forefront identity manager >synchronization service on local computer. for more >information, review the system event log. if this is a non->microsoft service contact the service vendor, and refers to >service specific error code -2146234334"

The FIMService didn't start until I modified its registry records; when using "*provided by settingsProvider.dll*" value for databaseName and databaseServer it didn't work.

The database and SharePoint are on the same server. The sql instance is Service Pack 1. SharePoint 2010. The sql connection is established (checked through Data Source). Automatic Delay didn't work. No helpful information in the event log.

Any Suggestion?

Comment: what build of SharePoint 2010 is this? SP1 / SP2 or a CU somewhere inbetween?

Comment: Thank you for the reply, it is without sp1, the version is 14.0.4762.1000

Answer (score 1):

First of all you don't need any registry hacks! It's not supported, and you will in most cases just make it worse.

What you should do is to follow Spencer Harbars excellent guides (including all the troubleshooting steps). You can find the guide here: http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010ups.aspx

You always succeed following those steps, one by one.

Comment: thank you for the reply and the link. i would like to add that the service was running. then it stopped. i am inspecting that it is something related to the database since the sql reporting service installed.